# How to iterate through HashMap of Some Class and List of Classes in Freemarker

Tags: java, freemarker

How can I iterate through this in freemarker template:

```
Map<Foo, List<Bar>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

I tried this, but no luck

```
<#list map?keys as key>
 <p>${key.blah()}</p>
  <#list map[key] as values values>
   <p>${value.bar()}</p>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through map/hash [values](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html):

```
<#list map?values as currentList>
  <#list currentList as value>
     <p>${value.bar()}</p>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

> A sequence that contains all the variables (the values in the key-value pairs) in the hash.